# VNext optionally label a build?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, vnext

I am looking to find out if it would be possible to optionally create a label based on a variable decided at build time.

At the moment Label Sources includes 3 options (Never, Always, On Success). I want to add/create a way that it will do it based on a variable.

For example

- 'Add Label -> true' - *Create label with some name 'Label_$(var)'*
- 'Add Label -> Milestone 2' - *Only make label if variable is not
  blank*

[image: Label from VSO]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible on the existing UI.

However you can label source with [**label command**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/label-command-team-foundation-version-control). So, you can try to write script based on your requirements with the label command, then add script manage task (eg: **Batch Script**, **Command Line** or **PowerShell** task) to run the scrip during the building.

For example to create a label:

```
tf label "LabelName" /owner:domain\me $/Project /version:T /recursive
```

You need to specify the root path of your label.